# Error on contentDescription for Image.asset in flutter dart

Tags: image, assets

When i make an AAB file from my flutter android code i get a warning that something is missing by "Google Play console". It suggests and points at that android:contentDescription is missing on the images and gifs i display using "Image.asset". I find nothing googling for hours. Its just a warning but it blocks my AAB
Does anyone have an idea?

Need to provide contentDescription to image or to Image.asset?